# SAGA Close Gaps - using the mask parameter?

Tags: qgis, interpolation, saga

I'm trying to interpolate cells in a gap in a raster layer using SAGA's Close Gaps tool. It works fine when I don't use the mask parameter, but when I do, it fails to generate the layer. There's not much documentation for this parameter so I don't really know how to troubleshoot it. Has anyone used it successfully?

The mask is to make it ignore the no data values of the raster outside the AOI border. I simply used a rasterized version of my AOI as the mask where the areas to be taken into account by Close Gaps are 1's and the nodata/0 cells are the mask.